# An invalid request was sent to the Sitecore layout service

Tags: helix, vs-helix-extension

I have a Sitecore 10.3 XP installation and a Visual Studio solution with Helix, where we are implementing components. My local Sitecore CM installation is running perfectly fine. However, when I am trying to run my VS solution, I am getting the error An invalid request was sent to the Sitecore layout service. We are using JSS headless implementation and even though everything is correctly installed and verified, I have an access denied message from the JSS API key:

> [https://unify-103-xp-sc.dev.local/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey={key}&sc_site={website-name}](https://unify-103-xp-sc.dev.local/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey=%7Bkey%7D&sc_site=%7Bwebsite-name%7D)

Any suggestion/direction will be highly appreciated.

I tested the graphQL API and it is working fine. I have re-installed JSS headless implementation and by looking at the folder structure it looked okay I verified that in the web database, the key is the same as in master I verified the publishing is done Somehow I am getting access denied for the JSS headless API key.

Comment: Where is it hosted? IIS or docker? Is the 403 coming from Sitecore. Possible to show a screenshot?

Comment: It is hosted on IIS. 403 is coming from Sitecore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the following :

1. Check if you have a Firewall or VPN which is denying access.
2. Note that Sitecore instance host and `LayoutServiceHost` can be different.

   E.g. in example below the Sitecore instance name in my local is `"https://searchdemosc.dev.local"` and Sitecore API or Layout Service Host is `"https://jsshomepage"`
3. Check the api key, deployment secret are correctly matching in `scjssconfig.jss` and `.env` files as shown below :

[image]

[image]

4. Check if https is used e.g. `SITECORE_API_HOST=https://jsshomepage` in `.env` file, then you have https binding in IIS. If not Try changing the host to http.
5. Make sure your Sitecore License has JSS license included

[image]

Comment: I am missing this.

Comment: I was using incorrect license file, so JSS license was missing. I have replaced it with correct one, now it works! Thank you!!!!